# Console Log behaviour - Cannot read Object property

Tags: angular, object, properties, undefined, undefined-behavior

I'm building an angular web app.

In the ngOnInit of the component:

```
 public ngOnInit() {
    this.log.debug("INSTANCE", this.Instance);
    this.log.debug("ACTIVITY",this.Instance.entity);
    this.log.debug("CREATED AT", this.Instance.created_at);
        // Other staff...
 }
```

I get the following result:
[image]

How can be possible so? I cannot read a property of the object that should be populated as the first log shows.

If I print the keys as suggested

```
Object.keys(this.Instance).forEach(data => {this.log.debug(data)});
```

I don't have the aspected key.

[image]

Comment: you're logging `"ACTIVITY"` with the second log, but your log output shows `"ENTITY"`. Are you sure that's not a different log somewhere, like in some getter for Instance?

Comment: @john04667 sorry was an old image for the same issue (several tests). I update the question

Comment: I think you are modifiying this.Instance in another place later. Could you create a stackblitz??

Comment: do you have any logic in class constructor or any thing attached to an input? If so please share. If you Object.keys(this.Instance).forEach(data => {console.log(data)})  , do you see the entity field in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console log is asynchronous. You get the reference of the object synchronously but not its properties. If the  object is  modified before you expand it, you see  the updated values.